# Keep latest revision of items in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of document names with some having revisions, such as:

```
docs = ["ab-14-001", "ab-14-001A", "ab-14-001B", "ab-14-002", "jk-9-12B", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]
```

I want to keep the latest revision on each one, meaning:

```
docs_final = ["ab-14-001B", "ab-14-002", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]
```

As you can see, some docs don't appear in their first state (without a letter rev at the end), they just show up with the rev letter (such as jk-9-12B).

Is there a quick way to parse through and separate this list into a docs_final and docs_old?

Thank you!

---

Clarification:
The letter at the end is the only thing used for the revision. So for example, these two documents are not revisions of each other, they are completely different:

```
"ab-14-001" and "ab-14-002A"
```

Comment: is it possible that e.g. have doc like `"ab-14-002"`, newer than `"ab-14-001B"`? Is it possible that you have 2-letter suffix, e.g. `"ab-14-001AA"`, newer than `"ab-14-001Z"`? in other words - is it just the leter indicating the revision, or also the number, e.g. 001

Comment: @buran on your first question, the answer is no (those two would be different docs). The letter is the only rev indication, and there will not be two letter revs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
docs = ["ab-14-001", "ab-14-001A", "ab-14-001B", "ab-14-002", "jk-9-12B", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]
revisions = tuple(ascii_uppercase)
latest_docs = {}
for doc in sorted(docs):
    key = doc[:-1] if doc.endswith(revisions) else doc
    latest_docs[key] = doc

print(list(latest_docs.values()))
```

output

```
['ab-14-001B', 'ab-14-002', 'io-34-003', 'jk-9-12C']
```

It can be shortened with using dict comprehension, but I would definitely go for the one above

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
docs = ["ab-14-001", "ab-14-001A", "ab-14-001B", "ab-14-002", "jk-9-12B", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]
latest_docs = {doc[:-1] if doc.endswith(tuple(ascii_uppercase)) else doc:doc for doc in sorted(docs)}
print(list(latest_docs.values()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (I'm supposing your list `docs` is sorted):

```
from itertools import groupby

docs = ["ab-14-001", "ab-14-001A", "ab-14-001B", "jk-9-12B", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]

docs_old, docs_new = [], []
for _, g in groupby(docs, lambda k: k.rsplit('-', maxsplit=1)[0]):
    *a, b = g
    docs_old.extend(a)
    docs_new.append(b)

print('Old = ', docs_old)
print('New = ', docs_new)
```

Prints:

```
Old =  ['ab-14-001', 'ab-14-001A', 'jk-9-12B']
New =  ['ab-14-001B', 'jk-9-12C', 'io-34-003']
```

---

EDIT:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

docs = ["ab-14-001", "ab-14-001A", "ab-14-001B", "ab-14-002", "jk-9-12B", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]

docs_old, docs_new = [], []
for _, g in groupby(docs, lambda k: re.search(r'(.*?)[A-Z]*$', k).group(1)):
    *a, b = g
    docs_old.extend(a)
    docs_new.append(b)

print('Old = ', docs_old)
print('New = ', docs_new)
```

Prints:

```
Old =  ['ab-14-001', 'ab-14-001A', 'jk-9-12B']
New =  ['ab-14-001B', 'ab-14-002', 'jk-9-12C', 'io-34-003']
```

Comment: I have added a clarification to my question above. The revision is determined only by the letter. In your case, if we have a doc "ab-14-002", that will be kept and the other "ab-14-001" docs will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this following code example for such cases of article names. Be careful though, as this only works for versions without including dashes ("-"). Version numbers/revision numbers are the set of numbers after the last dash. If the revision naming style changes the code has to be adapted correspondingly.

```
docs = ["ab-14-001", "ab-14-001A", "ab-14-001B", "jk-9-12B", "jk-9-12C", "io-34-003"]

#sort articles:
docs.sort()

#split identifier into article and revision number (version number) as tuple
splitted = [x.split('-') for x in docs]
revisions = [("-".join(doc[:-1]), doc[-1]) for doc in splitted]

#iterate over same doc and overwriting older versions with the newest found:
result = ["-".join([doc, version]) for (doc, version) in {x[0]: x[1] for x in revisions}.items()]

print(result)
```

As an alternative, this oneliner will also return a list of the latest versions

```
#One Liner:
result = ["-".join([d, v]) for (d, v) in {x[0]: x[1] for x in [("-".join(doc[:-1]), doc[-1]) for doc in [x.split('-') for x in docs]]}.items()]
```